# Differences between list.sublist() and stream.limit()

Tags: java, collections

I have two version of code which truncate an existing list:

version 1:

```
List<String> myList = User.getAllNames();
myList = myList.stream().sorted(sortByName).limit(5).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

version 2:

```
List<String> myList = User.getAllNames();
myList.sort(sortByName);
myList = myList.subList(0, 5 - 1);
```

version 3:

```
List<String> myList = User.getAllNames();
myList = new ArrayList<BacktestResult>(myList.subList(0, 5 - 1));
```

You can assume, that no other objects have a reference to the clipped elements. Both versions truncate `myList` by reassign. As **version 2** uses only `subList` which is baked by its origin list, I'm in doubt if **version 2** also removes the clipped elements totally from the java heap (after garbage collection) like **version 1** does.

**The main thing I need to know is, if version 2 also removes the clipped elements totally from the java heap (after garbage collection) like version 1 does.**

Comment: Answering your bold-indicated question: in short, there are many differences.

Comment: The main thing I need to know is, as I stated in the question: "if version 2 also removes the clipped elements totally from the java heap (after garbage collection) like version 1 does".

Comment: Neither does it in principle. `subList` returns a _view_ backed by the original list so you can consider all list elements are "pinned" to the heap therefore reachable with strong references at least while the list is alive.

Comment: And, I'd probably wouldn't call it "truncation": the original list in both cases remains unaffected. Removing the elements using `remove()` would really make it truncated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm in doubt if version 2 also removes the clipped elements totally from the java heap (after garbage collection)

Assuming no other objects have a reference to the clipped elements, they will be eligible for garbage collection in the case of version 1.

In the case of version 2, since the sublist produced is a "view" of the original list, the sublist needs to keep a reference to the original list, which contains all the clipped elements. Therefore, those clipped elements will not be eligible for garbage collection.

Version 3 is similar to version 1. You discard the view produced by `sublist`, so it will be eligible for GC. `myList` becomes a new list that only has references to the first elements of the original. Now no variable directly or indirectly refers to the last elements of the original list, so they are eligible for GC.

That said, this will probably not matter unless your lists have a *lot* of elements.

Comment: Thanks. I came up with another version (version 3, I added above). Maybe you can adapt your answer. I think, *version 3* behaves like *version 2* in terms of to be eligable for garbage collection..

Comment: @nimo23 This is similar to version 1. You discard the view produced by `sublist`, so it will be eligible for GC. `myList` becomes a new list that only has references to the first elements of the original, so the last elements are eligible for GC.